# Association path between 2 Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have a few Rails models. Here's a similar example list:

- one house belongs to a neighborhood
- one neighborhood belongs to a city
- one city belongs to a state
- one state belongs to a country
- one user belongs to a house

I would like to get a very magic function that I could use as follows:

```
(resource, scope, scope_ids) => {...}
```

a successful call would look like:

```
("house", "country", [30]) => { neighborhood: { city: { state: { country: [30] } } } }
("house", "state", [1,2,3]) => { neighborhood: { city: { state: [1,2,3] } } }
```

and a failing call would return:

```
("house", "people", [1,2,3]) => { id: -1 }
```

I would like to do this auto-magically so anything hardcoded would not be acceptable.

EDIT:

I would like to achieve the above result since I'm developing an authorization layer with CanCanCan that allows to do stuff like:

```
can :read, House, { neighborhood: { city: { state: { name: "Illinois" }}}}
```

Considered the above syntax, I would like to auto-magically generate permissions such as (where for example "own_neightborhood" is the neightborhood of the user being authorized and "others_houses" are the houses of the users different from the one being authorized):

```
# permission read_own_neighborhood_houses should generate:
can :read, House, { neighborhood: { users: {id: user.id } }

# permission read_own_state_cities should generate:
can :read, City, { state: { cities: { houses: { users: {id: user.id } } } } } } }

# permission read_others_neighborhoods_states should generate: 
can :read, State, { cities: { neighborhoods: { houses: { users: { id: User.where.not(id: user.id) } } } } }
```

Comment: So just to clarify; you want to ask your rails application how to get to one model from another through associations you've defined?

Comment: Yes I believe that would a clearer way to explain it

Comment: I do need the hash though, exactly as explained.

Comment: When rails loads your models it is rather lazy about it.  That means that your application might know about the house model but might not yet know about the city model.  So you would get associations that could not be followed even though the path does exist.  I think you could fix that with `config.eager_load = true` in your Application config though that will increase application boot time.

Comment: Ok let's assume then that I can eager load my application, can you think of a way of getting the path?

Comment: You say path, do you mean a URL? This is very unclear.

Comment: Nope I don't mean url I mean the an hash describing the series of associations to go from a model to another

Comment: Ok can you explain why? I ask because it seems like you are trying to do something that might be done easier in a different way. What are trying to achieve ultimately? "...to go from a model to another" is vague and does not seem to align with usual Rails conventions.

Comment: I'm realizing I probably need a tree to do this which needs to compose an hash with plural/singular keys. Anyway I did write a little explanation above.

Comment: Ok, that's quite a bit more clear. When you say "generate" what do you want to get back, a string? An array? `"can :read, House, { neighborhood: { users: {id: user.id } }"` is different than `[can :read, House, { neighborhood: { users: {id: user.id } }]`. It sounds like you are passing this to CanCan, what is it expecting as far as the type of object?

Comment: the method signature is defined as can(symbol, Model, hash). Does that make sense?

Comment: what I would like to generate is only the last argument aka hash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165603/discussion-between-beartech-and-pnknrg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly requires quite a bit of meta-programming. This could be a start using the `reflections_on_all_associations` method...

Given `permission read_own_state_cities`

```
def permission(perms)
  @perms = perms.split('_')  #['read', 'own', 'state', 'cities']
  @model = @perms[-1].singularize.capitalize.constantize   #City
  @action = @perms[0].to_sym   #:read
  @ownership = @perms[1].to_sym   #:own
  @top_level = @perms[2]   #:state

  hash_items = []
  current_level = @top_level
  until current_level = :user do
    hash_items << current_level
    current_level = current_level.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).first.name.to_sym
  end   #[:state, :cities, :neighborhoods]

  @hash = hash_items.reverse.inject({users: {}}) { |a, n| { n => a } } #{state: {cities: {neigborhoods: {users: {}}}}}
end
```

This is as far as I can get easily without having your actual situation to test against. You'll need to address how you decide what goes into the `users: {}` hash based on the value of `@ownership`. That should give you most everything you need to end up building a `can....` on the fly.